# Pass a ball between players: multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, java-threads

I'm writing a code to kind of pass a ball between 4 players numbered 1 to 4, so it goes 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 then 4 to 3 to 2 to 1. but I'm getting inconsistent results, I tried the debugger but I can't figure out how to move past the first 2 threads.
here is the code:

```
package Ball_Game;

public class Team_A extends Thread {
    int ID;
    Ball ball=new Ball();
    String phase="First-phase";
  public Team_A(int ID, Ball ball) {
      this.ball=ball;
      this.ID=ID;
  }
 @Override 
 public void run() {
     synchronized (ball) {
     while(phase.contains("First-phase")){ 
        
             if (ID==ball.nbr_player) {
                ball.throw_ball();
                
                if(ID!=4) {
                    ball.increment();
                    System.out.println(ball.nbr_player);
                    ball.notifyAll();
                    
                }else {
                    phase="Second-phase";
                    System.out.println(phase);
                   
                }
            }else {
                try {
                    ball.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }    
        } 

    while(phase.contains("Second-phase")){ 
           
         if (ID==ball.nbr_player) {
            ball.throw_ball_back();
            if(ball.nbr_player>1) {
                ball.decrement();
                ball.notifyAll();
            }else {
                phase="First-phase";
                  
            }
        }else {
            try {
                ball.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    } 
}
 }}
```

this is the ball class :

```
package Ball_Game;

public class Ball{
    int nbr_player=1;
    public synchronized void throw_ball() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" :throws ball");
    }
    public synchronized void throw_ball_back() {
        System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName()+" :throws ball back");
    }
    public synchronized void increment() {
        nbr_player++;
    }
    public synchronized void decrement() {
        nbr_player--;
    }
}
```

when I try to execute it it keeps going between thread 3 and 4 back and forth without going through 1 and 2 and I don't get why.

Comment: ID=4 throws ball and updates _its own instance of phase (to second-phase)_ meaning the other players (threads) still think they are in phase1.  So ID=4 transitions to 2nd phase (and decrements), ID=3 (still in phase 1) increments...and so on.  (something like that).  All players of team need to use the same `phase`.

Comment: damn it, is it like the difference between the thread class and interface runnable? because im using the class. also why arent thread 2 and 1 using their phase to?

Comment: In the constructor, you provide an `ID` and _one_ instance of a `Ball` - I'd recommend also providing a mutable, thread-safe version of the current phase.  All players need to "see" and "use" the same instance of phase.  (There's more than one way to do this.)

Comment: Very hacked up code. Need to rethink the implementation.

Comment: so i pass the phase variable as an argument in the constructor for threads?

Comment: K.Nicholas yeah it's the first i wrote lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. Fix your grammar please.

Players should catch and throw the ball, but I don't see any need for a Ball class. What property or logic does it have. It just gets tossed around like junior developers.

Logically I see a Player and a Team. A Player extends a Thread, it has a life, so to speak. A player can catch and throw a ball to the next player. The logic of who gets the ball next is determined by the Team.  When a ball is passed to the next player, the entire team is notified, and the Player who has the ball passes it to the next player. All other players wait.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!gameOver) {
            try {
                synchronized (team) {
                    if (hasBall) {
                        Player nextPlayer = team.getNextPlayer(playerId);
                        nextPlayer.catchBall();
                        hasBall = false;
                        team.notifyAll();
                    } else {
                        team.wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

A Team is made up of players and the Team contains logic to determine who gets the ball next.

```
    public Player getNextPlayer(int currentPlayer) {
        switch (currentDirection) {
            case NEXT:
                if ( currentPlayer >= numPlayers) {
                    currentDirection = DIRECTION.PRIOR;
                }
                break;
            case PRIOR:
                if ( currentPlayer <= 1) {
                    currentDirection = DIRECTION.NEXT;
                }
                break;
        }
        int nextPlayer = currentDirection == DIRECTION.NEXT ? currentPlayer + 1 : currentPlayer - 1;
        return players.get(nextPlayer-1);
    }
```

The rest is just housekeeping.

```
public class Player extends Thread {
    private final Team team;
    private final int playerId;
    private boolean hasBall;
    private boolean gameOver;

    public Player(Team team, int playerId) {
        this.team = team;
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.hasBall = false;
        this.gameOver = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!gameOver) {
            try {
                synchronized (team) {
                    if (hasBall) {
                        Player nextPlayer = team.getNextPlayer(playerId);
                        nextPlayer.catchBall();
                        hasBall = false;
                        team.notifyAll();
                    } else {
                        team.wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void catchBall() {
        hasBall = true;
        System.out.println("Ball caught by " + playerId);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        gameOver = true;
    }

    public void printState() {
        System.out.println("Player " + playerId + (hasBall ? " has ball." : " does NOT have ball."));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Team {
    private final int numPlayers;
    private final List<Player> players;
    private enum DIRECTION {NEXT, PRIOR}
    private DIRECTION currentDirection;

    public Team(int numPlayers) {
        this.numPlayers = numPlayers;
        players = new ArrayList<>(numPlayers);
        currentDirection = DIRECTION.NEXT;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
            players.add(new Player(this, i+1));
        }
    }

    public void playCatch() {
        players.forEach(Thread::start);
        players.get(0).catchBall();
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
    public void stopGame() {
        players.forEach(Player::gameOver);
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
        players.forEach(p-> {
            try {
                p.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        players.forEach(Player::printState);
    }
    public Player getNextPlayer(int currentPlayer) {
        switch (currentDirection) {
            case NEXT:
                if ( currentPlayer >= numPlayers) {
                    currentDirection = DIRECTION.PRIOR;
                }
                break;
            case PRIOR:
                if ( currentPlayer <= 1) {
                    currentDirection = DIRECTION.NEXT;
                }
                break;
        }
        int nextPlayer = currentDirection == DIRECTION.NEXT ? currentPlayer + 1 : currentPlayer - 1;
        return players.get(nextPlayer-1);
    }
}
```

The description of the problem solution reads equally well for both a layperson (product owner) and a technical person. This is a good thing.